# Passing value of dropdown in dojo.connect

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I am using dojo.connect on select box to handle functionality. I want to get dropdown value.

This is the HTML

```
<select class="drop-down">
  <option value="0">option1</option>
  <option value="1">option2</option>
</select>
```

Following is the Javascript written in dojo

```
var selectBox = dojo.query('.drop-down');
dojo.connect(selectBox[0],'onchange',this,this.toggleForm);
```

Here, Is there any way to pass the value through the function `toggleForm` in `dojo.connect` so that I  can get the value in `toggleForm` function?

Comment: What's your Dojo Toolkit version? I suppose it's  <= 1.6 right?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your toggleForm function to take an "event" parameter.  Through that event parameter you should be able to get the new value of the element that generated the event:

```
toggleForm =function(event){
  console.log('toggleForm',event.srcElement.value);  
};

var selectBox = dojo.query('.drop-down');
dojo.connect(selectBox[0],'onchange',this,this.toggleForm);​
```